# Swift 3: Animate color fill of arc added to UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-graphics, cashapelayer

I wish to animate the color fill of a section of a pie chart. I create the pie chart by creating a `UIBezierPath()` for each piece of the pie and then use the `addArc` method to specify the size/constraints of the arc. To animate the pie chart segment, I want the color fill of the arc to animate from the center of the circle to the radius end. However, I am having trouble. I heard the `strokeEnd` `keyPath` animated from `0` to `1` should work, but there is no animation happening on the arcs (the arcs are just appearing at app launch).

```
let rad = 2 * Double.pi
let pieCenter: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
var start: Double = 0
for i in 0...data.count - 1 {
    let size: Double = Double(data[i])! / 100 // the percentege of the circle that the given arc will take
    let end: Double = start + (size * rad)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: pieCenter)
    path.addArc(withCenter: pieCenter, radius: frame.width / 3, startAngle: CGFloat(start), endAngle: CGFloat(end), clockwise: true)

    start += size * rad

    let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    lineLayer.bounds = self.bounds
    lineLayer.position = self.layer.position
    lineLayer.path = path.cgPath
    lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    lineLayer.fillColor = colors[i]
    lineLayer.lineWidth = 0

    self.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.fromValue = pieCenter
    animation.toValue = frame.width / 3 // radius
    animation.duration = 2.5

    lineLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```

I've seen a solution to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822790/uibezierpath-cashapelayer-animate-a-circle-filling-up), but it does not work for the individual arcs.

Comment: Any animation on the fill color would help me out. Right now, animation in the posted code does nothing.

Comment: You want the color to spread from the center of the circle out to the edges? Or does Rob's cross-fade animation meet your needs?

Comment: See my answer below. I wanted a clockwise fill animation of the whole pie chart. The solution was to create a mask that was added to each pie slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ensure a smooth, clockwise animation of the pie chart, you must perform the following steps in order:

- Create a new parent layer of type `CAShapeLayer`
- In a loop each pie chart slice to the parent layer
- In another loop, iterate through the sublayers (pie slices) of the parent layer and assign each sublayer a mask and animate that mask in the loop
- Add the parent layer to the main layer: `self.layer.addSublayer(parentLayer)`

In a nutshell, the code will look like this:

```
// Code above this line adds the pie chart slices to the parentLayer
for layer in parentLayer.sublayers! {
    // Code in this block creates and animates the same mask for each layer
}
```

Each animation applied to each pie slice will be a `strokeEnd` keypath animation from `0` to `1`. When creating the mask, be sure its `fillColor` property is set to `UIColor.clear.cgColor`.

Answer (score 5):

When you animate `strokeEnd`, that animates the stroke around the path, but not the fill of the path.

If you're looking for just any animation of the fill, easy options include animating the `fillColor` key path from `UIColor.clear.cgColor` to the final color. Or animate the `opacity` key path from 0 to 1.

```
func addPie(_ animated: Bool = true) {
    shapeLayers.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
    shapeLayers.removeAll()

    guard let dataPoints = dataPoints else { return }

    let center = pieCenter
    let radius = pieRadius
    var startAngle = -CGFloat.pi / 2
    let sum = dataPoints.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.value }

    for (index, dataPoint) in dataPoints.enumerated() {
        let endAngle = startAngle + CGFloat(dataPoint.value / sum) * 2 * .pi
        let path = closedArc(at: center, with: radius, start: startAngle, end: endAngle)
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.fillColor = dataPoint.color.cgColor
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shape.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shape.path = path.cgPath
        layer.addSublayer(shape)
        shapeLayers.append(shape)
        shape.frame = bounds

        if animated {
            shape.opacity = 0

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index) / Double(dataPoints.count)) {
                shape.opacity = 1
                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
                animation.fromValue = 0
                animation.toValue = 1
                animation.duration = 1
                shape.add(animation, forKey: nil)
            }
        }

        startAngle = endAngle
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

The delaying of the animations give it a slightly more dynamic effect.

If you want to get fancy, you can play around with animations of `transform` of the entire `CAShapeLayer`. For example, you can scale the pie wedges:

```
func addPie(_ animated: Bool = true) {
    shapeLayers.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
    shapeLayers.removeAll()

    guard let dataPoints = dataPoints else { return }

    let center = pieCenter
    let radius = pieRadius
    var startAngle = -CGFloat.pi / 2
    let sum = dataPoints.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.value }

    for (index, dataPoint) in dataPoints.enumerated() {
        let endAngle = startAngle + CGFloat(dataPoint.value / sum) * 2 * .pi
        let path = closedArc(at: center, with: radius, start: startAngle, end: endAngle)
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.fillColor = dataPoint.color.cgColor
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shape.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shape.path = path.cgPath
        layer.addSublayer(shape)
        shapeLayers.append(shape)
        shape.frame = bounds

        if animated {
            shape.opacity = 0

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index) / Double(dataPoints.count) + 1) {
                shape.opacity = 1
                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
                animation.fromValue = CATransform3DMakeScale(0, 0, 1)
                animation.toValue = CATransform3DIdentity
                animation.duration = 1
                shape.add(animation, forKey: nil)
            }
        }

        startAngle = endAngle
    }
}
```

Yielding:

[image]

Or you can rotate the pie wedge shape layer about its center angle making it appear to angularly expand:

```
func addPie(_ animated: Bool = true) {
    shapeLayers.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
    shapeLayers.removeAll()

    guard let dataPoints = dataPoints else { return }

    let center = pieCenter
    let radius = pieRadius
    var startAngle = -CGFloat.pi / 2
    let sum = dataPoints.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.value }

    for (index, dataPoint) in dataPoints.enumerated() {
        let endAngle = startAngle + CGFloat(dataPoint.value / sum) * 2 * .pi
        let path = closedArc(at: center, with: radius, start: startAngle, end: endAngle)
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.fillColor = dataPoint.color.cgColor
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shape.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shape.path = path.cgPath
        layer.addSublayer(shape)
        shapeLayers.append(shape)
        shape.frame = bounds

        if animated {
            shape.opacity = 0

            let centerAngle = startAngle + CGFloat(dataPoint.value / sum) * .pi
            let transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi / 2, cos(centerAngle), sin(centerAngle), 0)

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index) / Double(dataPoints.count)) {
                shape.opacity = 1
                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
                animation.fromValue = transform
                animation.toValue = CATransform3DIdentity
                animation.duration = 1
                shape.add(animation, forKey: nil)
            }
        }

        startAngle = endAngle
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

I'd encourage you to not get too lost in the details of my `CAShapeLayer` and my model, but rather focus on the `CABasicAnimation` and the various `keyPath` values we can animate.

Comment: What is lineWidth?

Comment: A random property that holds the width of the stroke. It's not relevant here. Don't get lost in those details. Focus on the `CABasicAnimation` code, where I animate the `transform` property from something that rotates `.pi / 2` about the middle of the pie wedge back to identity. But see my full code here https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/17b4c1e0e09afeaca6ad6e183d315e3c.

Comment: Clever use of rotation. At first I couldn't figure out how you were getting that "expand outward from the center" look. It's because you're rotating around a radius of the circle centered on each wedge, and since the layers don't show perspective, it looks like the wedges are simply getting wider.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are after is a "clock wipe" effect that reveals your graph. If that's the case then there is a simpler way than creating a separate mask layer for each separate wedge of your pie chart. Instead, make each wedge of your graph a sublayer of a single layer, install a mask layer on that super-layer, and run a clock wipe animation on that super layer.

Here is a GIF illustrating a clock wipe animation of a static image:

[image: Clock wipe animation]

I wrote a post explaining how to do it, and linking to a Github project demonstrating it:

[How do you achieve a "clock wipe"/ radial wipe effect in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409212/how-do-you-achieve-a-clock-wipe-radial-wipe-effect-in-ios)

Comment: Yes I've seen your solution plenty of times lol. I used a variation of your solution which applied the same layer mask to each pie slice (sublayer).

Comment: Why? Do you want each slice of the pie chart to animate into place at the same time?

Comment: No, the pie chart animates just like your image above. If the mask's path is a `CAMutablePath` arc from 0 to 2PI and animation is `strokeEnd`, applying that same mask to each sublayer produces the "clock-wipe" effect. Your solution only works if we want to do a "clock-wipe" over one layer with no sublayers

Comment: I haven't tried it, but why can't you make all of the sublayers child layers of a layer to which you attach the mask and animate the clock wipe on the parent layer?

Comment: Intuitively that’s how you think it would work, but it didn’t work for me until I added different instances of the same mask to each sublayer

Answer (score 0):

reduce the arc `radius` to half and make the line twice as thick as the radius

```
let path = closedArc(at: center, with: radius * 0.5, start: startAngle, end: endAngle)
lineLayer.lineWidth = radius
```

set the `fillColor` to `clear`

Answer (score 0):

[image]I may be very late to the party. But if anyone are looking for smooth circle Pie chart animation try this:-

**In your ViewController class use below**

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
let chartView = PieChartView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        myView.addSubview(chartView)
        chartView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        chartView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        chartView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        chartView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        chartView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let segments = [Segment(value: 70, color: .systemBlue), Segment(value: 40, color: .systemCyan), Segment(value: 5, color: .systemTeal), Segment(value: 4, color: .systemMint), Segment(value: 5, color: .systemPurple)]
        
        chartView.segments = segments
    }
}
```

**Create below PieChartView class which will animate pieChart as well**

```
class PieChartView: UIView {

    /// An array of structs representing the segments of the pie chart
    var pieSliceLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var count = 0
    var startAngle = -CGFloat.pi * 0.5
    var segments = [Segment]() {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay() // re-draw view when the values get set
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        isOpaque = false // when overriding drawRect, you must specify this to maintain transparency.
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        addSlices()
      }
    
    
    func addSlices() {
        guard count < segments.count else {return}
        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2.0 - 20
        let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let valueCount = segments.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.value})
        for value in segments {
            let pieSliceLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            pieSliceLayer.strokeColor = value.color.cgColor
            pieSliceLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            pieSliceLayer.lineWidth = radius
            layer.addSublayer(pieSliceLayer)
            let endAngle = CGFloat(value.value) / valueCount * CGFloat.pi * 2.0 + startAngle
            pieSliceLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius/2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true).cgPath
            startAngle = endAngle
        }
        pieSliceLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        pieSliceLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        pieSliceLayer.lineWidth = radius
        let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * .pi / 2
        let endAngle: CGFloat =  -3 * .pi / 2
        pieSliceLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius/2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: false).cgPath
        pieSliceLayer.strokeEnd = 1
        layer.addSublayer(pieSliceLayer)
        startCircleAnimation()
    }
    
    private func startCircleAnimation() {
        pieSliceLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 1
        animation.toValue = 0
        animation.duration = 1.0
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.42, 0.00, 0.09, 1.00)
        pieSliceLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```